# Use the forEach function to add option elements to select HTML element

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, foreach, html-select

how to use the array .forEach function to iterate over a "users" array and populate the SELECT UI element with OPTION elements. Each OPTION should have its value set to the id of a given user, while its display text should be set to the user's name

```
 function displayUsers(users){
    users.forEach((users)=>{
      let sel = document.querySelector('.select-text');
      let opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.value=users.id;
      let userName=document.createTextNode(users.name);
      opt.appendChild(userName);
      sel.appendChild(opt);


  });
};
```

Comment: If performance matters for your app, I would suggest to modify `innerHTML` rather than manipulate DOM, the former may take one simple line of code and may operate up to 40 times [faster](https://jsperf.com/population-options/1). Check out my answer below for details.

Comment: Is there something not working with what you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for.

```js
const displayUsers = (users) => {
  users.forEach((user) => {
    const option = document.createElement("OPTION");
    const name = document.createTextNode(user.name);
    option.value = user.id;
    option.appendChild(name);
    document.querySelector('select').appendChild(option);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```js
function displayUsers(users) {
  var sel = document.querySelector('.select-text');
  users.forEach(user => {
    let opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = users.id;
    opt.textContent += user.name // or opt.innerHTML += user.name
    sel.appendChild(opt);
  });
};

const users = [{
  name: "Foo"
}, {
  name: "Bar"
}]

displayUsers(users)
```

```html
<select class="select-text"></select>
```

you better declare one the select and put it out of the forEach function

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, we are required to use textContent rather than inner HTML.

Comment: isn't it the same with textContent instead of innerHTML ?

Answer (score 2):

My favorite method to do that is using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) it is faster than DOM manipulation and pretty concise.

```js
const targetNode = document.getElementById('users');

const srcArray = [{id: 1, name: 'user1'}, {id: 2, name: 'user2'}, {id: 3, name: 'user3'}];

targetNode.innerHTML = srcArray.reduce((options, {id,name}) => 
  options+=`<option value="${id}">${name}</option>`, 
  '<option value="" selected></option>');
```

```html
<select id="users"></select>
```

Comment: It's probably better to split this into several lines since the OP is apparently a beginner with HTML/JS. It also makes it easier to read without having to scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare your variable `sel` outside the loop.

```js
function displayUsers(users){
  let sel = document.querySelector('.select-text');
  users.forEach((users)=>{
      let opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.value=users.id;
      let userName=document.createTextNode(users.name);
      opt.appendChild(userName);
      sel.appendChild(opt);
  });
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  displayUsers([{id: 1, name: 'John'}, {id: 2, name: 'Doe'}]);
})
```

```html
<select class="select-text"></select>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! for some reason, it's not passing the test conditions designed by the program I am applying to. Not sure why. I will continue playing around with it to see.

Answer (score 1):

```
array.forEach(()=>{
  select.innerHTML += '<option>hello</option>' 
})
```

i think this will help

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do it with JQuery:

```
data.forEach(function(key,index){
$('#seccion_exp').append(
                         '<option value="'+key.id+'">'+key.nombreSeccion+'</option>'
                  )
 })
```

The *data* is the JSON array I used in my case given by PHP, the "#seccion_exp" is the id I gave to the select, that is actually empty. So if we append the options using the names of the fields on dbase you should be able to display the options and use the actual values from dbase.

This is the HTML part:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Select what you need</label>
         <select class="form-control" id="seccion_exp">
             <option>Choose..</option>
         </select>
</div>
```

Hope this help someone.